# Python returns 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:' when trying to create a file with time and date

Tags: python, string, file, datetime

I want to create a script that creates a file named after the current time and date in **dd/mm/YY H:M:S** format, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
open(str(dt_string), 'w+')
```

However, when I try to run it it returns *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '25/06/2022 13:02:32'*

Isn't Python supposed to create a new file, when you try to open one that doesn't exist?

I've tried using *now* as a string to use as a file name an it worked perfectly

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
#dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
open(str(now), 'w+')
```

Why doesn't it accept *dt_string* as a file name?

Comment: your filename uses path separators `/` which won't work, and colons `:` might also be a problem on some systems. try using dashes or underscores instead, e.g. with a formatting directive like `"%d-%m-%Y_%H%M%S"`.

Comment: side note: if you want to create multiple files like this and want to be able to sort them by filename later on, use a datetime format with *increasing resolution* (left to right), e.g. `%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks to FObersteiner

The problem was with '/' separators. I used dashes instead an everything worked perfectly. I also included ':' and there wasn't any problem with it.